# Stop WordPress from using html entities in <title></title>

Tags: wordpress, seo, title, html-entities

Google only cares about 65 characters of the `<title></title>` of any web page. It's a rare and precious space in terms of SEO and we want it to contain as many keywords as possible. However, WordPress keeps converting single character such as '-' into html entities '`&#8211;`' that is unwanted and lengthy, unnecessarily taking up precious space in `<title></title>`

See [this page](http://www.avivaly.com/product/silk-wedding-dress-the-princess-bride/) for example.

How do I stop WordPress doing the entities conversion in `<title></title>`?

Comment: I'm sorry if i don't get it, but the titles are displaying nicely and it would be something that i'll still click if i were looking for INDIVIDUAL wedding dresses...

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear. See the changes I made to the question. WordPress automatically converts '-' to '`&#8211;`' which takes 6 more bytes in `<title></title>`. I want to stop it from doing it so.

Comment: do you have any plugins enabled that are automatically converting it to &#8211;?

Comment: Maybe converting back with **html_entity_decode()** will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 65 character limit is a guess from SEOs and I've recently read one article showing how the number of characters shown varies by the width of the characters used.

And I don't think Google is that dumb that it can't decode characters in html!

If it shows up fine, don't worry.

Answer (score 1):

Found on `http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60379/how-to-prevent-automatic-conversion-of-dashes-to-ndash` and edited :

In your **functions.php**:

add `remove_filter( 'the_title', 'wptexturize' );`

And the same for the_excerpt or the_content (if required).

Comment: Thanks but while it seems this would work, it doesn't. It's weird.

Comment: Uhh, you might need to wait a while in Google for changes to happen though. Or is it still the same in your Titles?

Comment: Yes, it's still the same in my title. WordPress is still converting - to `&#8211;`. I don't think this has anything to do with Google?

Comment: I'm not very sure why its still converting, once again do you have any plugins that also support that conversion?